# Ajax - Printing a JSON value from all Indexes on the Reponse

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the following JSON response:

```
    {
    "SlbOperEnhGroupRealServerTable":[{
    "RealServGroupIndex": "All_ISP",
    "ServIndex": "ISP1",
    "State": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "IP": "192.168.30.1" ,
    "Descr": "",
    "RuntimeStatus": 2
    },
    {
    "RealServGroupIndex": "All_ISP",
    "ServIndex": "ISP2",
    "State": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "IP": "192.168.40.1" ,
    "Descr": "",
    "RuntimeStatus": 1
    }]                                   
}
```

I want to print the value of "RuntimeStatus" of all of the indexes in the JSON response.

So, I can use this (which works):

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data['SlbOperEnhGroupRealServerTable'][0].RuntimeStatus)
    alert(data['SlbOperEnhGroupRealServerTable'][1].RuntimeStatus)
    },
```

But I don't know how many indexes that contain "RuntimeStatus" will be in the response, so I want to print the values all available indexes of "RuntimeStatus" in the response.

Do you know how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ['SlbOperEnhGroupRealServerTable'].length; i++) {
   console.log(data['SlbOperEnhGroupRealServerTable'][i].RuntimeStatus);
}
```

Here I am using `console.log` instead of `alert` for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
var data = {
    "SlbOperEnhGroupRealServerTable":[{
    "RealServGroupIndex": "All_ISP",
    "ServIndex": "ISP1",
    "State": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "IP": "192.168.30.1" ,
    "Descr": "",
    "RuntimeStatus": 2
    },
    {
    "RealServGroupIndex": "All_ISP",
    "ServIndex": "ISP2",
    "State": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "IP": "192.168.40.1" ,
    "Descr": "",
    "RuntimeStatus": 1
    }]                                   
};

data.SlbOperEnhGroupRealServerTable.map(function(item) {
  if(item.RuntimeStatus) {
    console.log(item.RuntimeStatus);
  }
})
```